# how do I escape dragonsreach dungeon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Whiterun, I stole something and went to jail. I went down and then as I turned around, I got stuck between a wardrobe and tried sprinting out. Then I tried jumping. Neither of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a console or a PC? If the latter, just open your console and type in `coc whiterunorigin` teleporting you to the Whiterun marketplace. If the former, or you don't want to use the console, loading a previous autosave/save is an option if available, although if you're asking here it probably isn't. Otherwise, just spam jump and sheathe/unsheathe and pray.

Comment: I tried, prayed, and somehow made it out. I picked outisde and got battered by a guard. And Dova, it's my second play through =).

Comment: Heh, glad I was some help. Had to assume the bare minimum XD